# WM_COMMAND message not being received by the Windows Procedure

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, user-interface, contextmenu, message-queue

I am creating a system tray program with a shortcut/context menu, but I can't seem to receive WM_COMMAND messages in the Windows Procedure. It simply doesn't send when I click the menu item, and I've been checking for ages whether I have set up the menu correctly.

Here is my code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "resource.h"
#define WM_TRAYICON (WM_USER + 0x0001) //a custom message for the notification icon

HWND hwnd; //window handle
HINSTANCE hinst; //module handle
WNDCLASSEX wnd; //window class
MSG msg; //event message or notification
NOTIFYICONDATA nid; //notification icon object
HMENU cmenu;
MENUITEMINFO menuitem1;
MENUITEMINFO menuitem2;
CURSORINFO cursor;

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWProc ( HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    switch( uMsg )
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        printf("asfd\r\n");
        break;
    case WM_CREATE:
        printf("just created\r\n");
        break;
    case WM_TRAYICON:
        switch( LOWORD(lParam) )
        {
        case WM_CONTEXTMENU:
            GetCursorInfo( &cursor );
            //printf("xPos: %d\r\nyPos = %d\r\n\r\n", xPos, yPos );
            TrackPopupMenuEx( cmenu, TPM_RETURNCMD | TPM_LEFTBUTTON | TPM_NOANIMATION | TPM_HORIZONTAL | TPM_VERTICAL, cursor.ptScreenPos.x, cursor.ptScreenPos.y,  hwnd, NULL );
            //DestroyMenu(
            break;
        }
        break;
    case WM_INITMENU:
        printf("open menu\r\n");
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        //clean things up
        Shell_NotifyIcon( NIM_DELETE, &nid );
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc( hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam );
}

void main()
{
    int result;

    hinst = GetModuleHandle( NULL );
    cursor.cbSize = sizeof( cursor );

    memset( &wnd, 0, sizeof( wnd ) );
    wnd.cbSize = sizeof( wnd );
    wnd.lpszClassName = "MainWClass";
    wnd.lpfnWndProc = MainWProc;
    wnd.hInstance = hinst;
    result = RegisterClassEx( &wnd );

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx
        (
        0, //extended styles
        wnd.lpszClassName, //class name
        "Main Window", //window name
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL | WS_MINIMIZEBOX, //style tags
        CW_USEDEFAULT, //horizontal position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, //vertical position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, //width
        CW_USEDEFAULT, //height
        (HWND) NULL, //parent window
        (HMENU) NULL, //class menu
        (HINSTANCE) wnd.hInstance, //some HINSTANCE pointer
        NULL //Create Window Data?
        );
    if( !hwnd )
    {
        printf("CreateWindowEx failed: %d\n", GetLastError() );
        Sleep( INFINITE );
    }

    nid.cbSize = sizeof( nid );
    nid.hWnd = hwnd;
    nid.uID = 1;
    nid.uVersion = NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4;
    nid.uCallbackMessage = WM_TRAYICON;
    nid.hIcon = LoadIcon( hinst, MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDI_ICON1 ) );
    strcpy( nid.szTip, "My Tooltip!" );
    nid.uFlags = NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_ICON | NIF_TIP | NIF_SHOWTIP;

    cmenu = CreatePopupMenu();
    menuitem1.cbSize = sizeof( menuitem1 );
    menuitem1.fMask = MIIM_TYPE;
    menuitem1.fType = MFT_STRING;
    menuitem1.hSubMenu = NULL;
    //menuitem1.cch = ;
    menuitem1.dwTypeData = "Open a world of wonder!";
    InsertMenuItem( cmenu, 0, true, &menuitem1 );

    if( ! Shell_NotifyIcon( NIM_ADD, &nid ) )
    {
        printf("Shell_NotifyIcon( NIM_ADD, &nid ) failed.\r\n");
        Sleep( INFINITE );
    }
    if( ! Shell_NotifyIcon( NIM_SETVERSION, &nid ) )
    {
        printf("Shell_NotifyIcon( NIM_SETVERSION, &nid ) failed.\r\n");
        Sleep( INFINITE );
    }

    UpdateWindow( hwnd );
    for( ; ; )
    {
        if( GetMessage(&msg, hwnd, 0, 0) )
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using printf in GUI based application? Use TRACE macros to see output in Debug Window.

Comment: Meh I prefer to see it on the console.

Comment: That's your choice. But doesn't make sense to me. Debug-Windows is nothing but a console. Launching another console for GUI doesn't mean logical. Your GUI program should start with `WinMain`, and not `main` (There are many reasons). So, if your program starts with `WinMain`, printf wont work.

Comment: You can get printf output from a windows program provided you start it explicitly with a STDOUT set: `c:\users\yourname> program.exe > output.txt 2>&1` or from start->run or a shortcut `cmd.exe /s /c "  program.exe > output.txt 2>&1 "`. A Windows subsystem program CAN have a STDOUT, it just doesn't have one by default. Conversely, Console subsystem programs have one by default but can be created without.

Comment: @Ajay I will transition to WinMain when it's finished, but for now I can enjoy the console. I'm not using MFC so I don't think I can use TRACE.

Comment: You can use `OutputDebugString` function.

Comment: @Ajay Thanks! It's always a pain removing all the printf() calls at the end of it all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um, you passed the `TPM_RETURNCMD` flag which means "don't post a `WM_COMMAND` message. Just return the value you would have posted."

Comment: Oh shit....I thought "returns the menu item identifier" means return it to the wndproc. Thanks so much!